# Why And in joining clause not filtering the data

Tags: oracle

The below code is written to get the all the parent and child relationship and want to understand  why the And is not filtering the records but where does.
    e.g-

```
select 
s.name, 
s.status,
s.start_date_active,
s.end_date_active,
s.salesrep_number,

p.name Parent_name,

p.status Parent_status,
p.start_date_active Parent_start_date_active,
p.end_date_active Parent_end_date_active,

FROM XXX_XX_SALESREPS s
left outer join XXX_XX_SALESREPS p
on s.attribute1 = p.salesrep_id
**and s.attribute1 = '100003916'**
```

this above query give all the rows from table s  and do not filter it on '100003916' . But when i used ..

```
select 
s.name, 
s.status,
s.start_date_active,
s.end_date_active,
s.salesrep_number,

p.name Parent_name,

p.status Parent_status,
p.start_date_active Parent_start_date_active,
p.end_date_active Parent_end_date_active,

FROM XXX_XX_SALESREPS s
left outer join XXX_XX_SALESREPS p
on s.attribute1 = p.salesrep_id
**where  s.attribute1 = '100003916'**
```

this query gives me just filter record. Why can anyone please answer it. Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first case `and s.attribute1 = '100003916'` is part of your join criteria - and since it is `left outer join` it wont serve as a filter.